# generate random numbers in fork loop

Tags: c, linux

i want to generate random numbers between 0 and 20, 10 times inside child and pass them every time to parent. I have this:

```
    int fd[2];
        srand(time(NULL));
        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            printf("error sto pipe");
        }
        int customer = fork(), number;
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){ 
        if (customer == 0){
            close(fd[0]);       
            number = rand()%21;
            write(fd[1], &number, sizeof(int));
            close(fd[1]);   
        }else{
            close(fd[1]);
            int num;
            read(fd[0], &num, sizeof(int));
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("num: %d", num);
            if (catalog[num].item_count>0){
                catalog[num].item_count--;
                printf("Item: %s\n",
catalog[num].description);
                printf("Price: %f\n", catalog[num].price);
                printf("Diathesimo stock: %d\n", catalog[num].item_count);  
            }else{
                printf("Stock is zero for: %s\n", catalog[num].description);
                
            }       
             wait(NULL);
        }
        sleep(1);
        }
```

i keep taking only the same numbers each time the code runs

Comment: Think about what `wait(NULL);` is doing, and in which process you should have it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah you are right, i changed it and placed it to else but still i keep getting only one number out of 20 in every loop.

Comment: Did you seed the random number generator?  I typically just use `srand( time( NULL ) )` for "everyday" (i.e.: non-cryptographic) random numbers.  Otherwise you *will* just get the same numbers each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in the very first iteration you close the pipe between the child and parent processes.

That means every iteration after that, the `write` and `read` calls will *fail*, even if you don't notice it.

The reason you get the "same" number over and over is because `read` in the parent process just doesn't read anything into `num`, so the last value of `num` is kept.

Solution: Don't close the pipe between the processes (`fd[1]` in the child process, and `fd[0]` in the parent, should be kept open).

The lesson to be learned here is that you should *always* check for errors.